# Biasing move base for pivot turns when stopped

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am working on a robot simulated in Gazebo.  Our environment has many rather narrow aisles that are ~2.5x the diameter of the robot in width.  Currently, when our robot needs to turn around in an aisle, it plans "sweeping turns," that is, where vx and vtheta are both non-zero.  This typically ends up with the robot moving too close to an obstacle and transitioning to recovery behaviors.  Is there a way to bias move_base toward pivot turns?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200996/biasing-move-base-for-pivot-turns-when-stopped/) by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 422 on 2015-01-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2015-03-12**:
We have the same issue with our robot, using the DWA Planner. If the 'bot is initially facing in the direction of the global plan, navigation works nicely. If the robot is given a goal directly behind, instead of simply pivoting in place, it does a big, lazy turn. I'm wondering: bug, or feature? :)

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2015-03-12**:
In other words, is this a tuning issue, or would it be smarter to add some additional code to turn the robot in the right direction before proceeding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bradley,

After some more experimentation and tuning, we've found two things:

1. We had `acc_lim_th` set too low.
2. As mentioned in the Navigation Tuning Guide, `sim_time` matters a **lot**.

With these set correctly, the planner selects "turn in-place" as a valid trajectory.

Another thing that's helping with our understanding of dwa_local_planner is to visualize the trajectory cost cloud, as described [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/192143/dwa_planner-trajectory_cloud-topic-not-showing-up/). We cut power to the robot's drive train, fire up rqt_reconfigure, then issue a nav goal in RViz. From there, we can watch the planner do its thing while tweaking the DWA-related params.

---

Originally posted by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) with karma: 567 on 2015-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30108/mcarr/) on 2017-05-17**:
Hey Rick, you mentioned tuning `sim_time` helps a lot. What were your findings? Did it manage a "in-place" rotation with a high or lower sim time? I'm having the same issue and I feel like a large `sim_time` causes these large sweeping trajectories. However a small value has poor ability to navigate

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2017-05-17**:
It's been a while, but if I remember correctly, it was "increase". Biggest help in picking a good sim time was visualizing the trajectories in RViz, while tweaking the params in rqt_reconfigure. As soon as we did that, tuning became *much* easier.

**Comment by [mcarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30108/mcarr/) on 2017-05-18**:
Hi Rick,
My problem was that when I set a goal directly behind the robot, the local planner failed to find a path. By viewing the trajectories, I could see my `acc_lim_th` was much too low (even though I had determined it experimentally). Increase this and it all works great now!

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2017-05-18**:
Glad to hear it! That trajectory visualization really lets you know what it's "thinking"; makes all the difference.